# For-loop in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog so I am having some problems working with if

Basically I have a 5 bit number, and a want to split it so I can have a 2 digits decimal number. For doing so I have this piece of code

```
reg [4:0] position, aux;
reg [3:0] display1, display2;
reg [2:0] secondDigit;

always @(negedge iKEY[1] or negedge iKEY[2]) begin
    aux = position;

    for(secondDigit = 2'b0; aux >= 5'b01010; secondDigit = secondDigit + 2'b01)
        aux = aux - 5'b01010;

    assign display1 = aux[3:0];
    assign display2 = {2'b0, secondDigit};

end
```

The problem is I am getting this message of

```
loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within 250 iterations
```

I also tried substituting the for loop for this while, but keep getting the same error

```
aux = position;
secondDigit = 2'b0;
while(aux > 5'b01010) begin
    aux = aux - 5'b01010;
    secondDigit = secondDigit + 2'b01;
end
```

Can somebody help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier if you divided your logic up into a two always blocks. One for combination logic and one for synchronous logic. In the combination logic should looks something like below. Note that the for-loop can unravel to three sequential if-statements.

```
integer index;
always @* begin // combination logic
  aux = position;
  secondDigit = 2'b00;
  for(index = 0; index < 3; index = index + 1) begin
    if(firstDigit >= 5'b0_1010) begin
      aux = aux- 5'b0_1010;
      secondDigit = secondDigit + 1'b1;
    end
  end
end
```

As Morgan mentioned, you should not use `@(negedge iKEY[1] or negedge iKEY[2])` because it will generate weird synthesis results. It looks like you intend to have a flop. I would recommend the following:

```
wire enable = !(iKEY[1] && iKEY[2]); // clocking signal
always @(posedge enable) begin // use enable as a clock
  display1 <= aux[3:0];
  display2 <= {2'b00,secondDigit[1:0]};
end
```

Working code with bare-bone test-bench : http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/245

Comment: I need to know which one of iKEY[1] or iKEY[2] has changed its status(they are buttons in the board), so I think that I need to have those ifs inside the always block

Comment: @J0rge you can sill use `iKEY` inside the block, the `enable` just allows the synthesizer to use it as a clock reference. I'm assuming you do not have actual clock running and that you want the outputs to come from a flop. Otherwise you should design for a latch. The synthesizer will not know what to do when it sees multiple edge sensitive signals unless it is clear which one is synchronous and which ones are asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved my biggest problem(separating the number) in a simpler manner, but your suggestions helped me understanting a little more of hardware logic

Answer (score 2):

I only use for loops in RTL which can be statically unrolled, this might be the case here but I do not see it.

You are using the loop to increment `secondDigit` while the condition is based on `aux`. To me this suggests a variable number of times around the loop.

The line `aux = aux - 5'b01010;` will be executed n times implying variable number of subtractors in parallel.

Although looking at your condition `aux >= 5'b01010` doe this not imply at most once around the loop? Would an if statement not be much simpler here?

It looks like you are doing the same as:

```
if ( aux >= 5'b01010 ) begin
  secondDigit = 2'b01 ;
  aux         = aux - 5'b01010;
end
```

NB: do not use assign inside always blocks it is just:

```
always @(negedge iKEY[1] or negedge iKEY[2]) begin
  display1 = aux[3:0];
  display2 = {2'b0, secondDigit};
end
```

What hardware are you trying to imply with `always@(negedge iKEY[1] or negedge iKEY[2])`?

Comment: The logic is Ok - the OP's using repeated subtraction to do binary to BCD conversion (ie. `aux/10` and `aux%10`). I think/hope he's not trying to synth it...

Comment: Yeah, I am doing successives subtractions in order to convert from binary to BCD, so in some cases I need mode than one step. And I am using an Altera DE2-70 as hardware

Comment: Ok, you need to think hardware, not software - see Morgan's answer for starters.

Comment: In your second always block (the synchronous one), you're using blocking assignments. Use `<=` instead of `=` to assign them in parallel.